# Symfony Edit Specific Related Records

Tags: symfony1

I have an app that I have a model that supports multiple addresses, but upfront I only want to allow the user to add/edit one address.

```
User
----
UserId

Address
----
UserId
Line1
...
```

I have the following to render the form for adding a new address, but how about existing records?  What do I need to add to my configure method in the User form?

```
    $this->embedForm("address", new AddressForm());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [More with Symfony: Advanced Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms). This chapter outlines a good way to embed multiple forms when dealing with 1-to-many relationships and should more than cover explaining what you need to do.